# How to marshall a managed cli::array<byte>^ into a managed structure?

Tags: .net, struct, c++-cli, marshalling

On C/CLI I´m trying to build a function that will convert a byte array buffer received from a managed class to a managed structure. The structure has some enums on its composition. Here is my code:

```
  public enum class ControlEnum {
        LOCAL,
        REMOTE,
        EMERGENCY,
        ERROR
    }


    public enum class StateEnum {
        ON, 
        OFF
    }

    public enum class TimeoutEnum {
        10SEC,
        30SEC,
        1MIN,
        5MIN
    }

    public enum class StatusEnum {
        OK,
        FAILURE
    }

    public ref struct ReportDataStruct{
        public:
             ControlEnum control;
             StateEnum state;
             TimeoutEnum timeout;
             Single value;
             Int32 attenuation;
    };

    public ref struct ReportStruct {
        public:
            StatusEnum reportStatus;
            DateTime reportDataTime;
            cli::array<byte>^ reportData;
    };
```

what I need is to map the `reportData` field from the `ReportStruct`  into the `ReportDataScruct` to be used by the application. By having a structured type I can access direct its fiels on the application;

In plain C++ I would build a simple function like:

```
ReportDataStruct& convert(ReportStruct& report)
{
    return (ReportDataStruct&) report.reportData;
}
```

What would be the equivalent on C++/CLI considering both structures are managed itens ? I´ve found examples using `System.Interop.Marshall` and `pin_ptr`, but I don´t know exactly where to go.

Comment: Where is that `array<byte>` coming from? Why are you receiving your class as a byte array instead of as the proper type?

Comment: `array<byte>` is a buffer that comes from a network operation in a C++ layer. The buffer must be mapped to the given structs to be used in the high level app.

Comment: So the member is declared wrong, reportData must be declared as type ReportDataStruct.  That it was once a byte[] array is a completely irrelevant implementation detail of the network layer.  The longer you delay making the conversion, the harder it gets.

Comment: I can´t. `reportData` can be of several different types depending of the report type that is received on a header field that is not represented on the code (`ReportHeaderStruct`). I illustrated the problem with the `ReportDataStruct` but in real I have several different structures to map `reportData`. I really need to marshal it in that context as I cannot change the layer below.

Comment: It would still be best to do the conversion from byte[] to the proper type as soon as possible. Either give `ReportStruct` several fields and have all but one of them as null, or make it so that `ReportDataStruct` is part of a class hierarchy, where `ReportStruct`'s field has one of several subclasses, or something like that.

Comment: It's also worth asking the question, where did that byte array come from in the first place? Yes, it arrived over the network, but where did the other side get it from? Did they take your .Net class and serialize it? Probably not, and that's the only way to be sure that what you're thinking of would work. What you should probably be aiming for is writing a `Deserialize()` method that takes the byte array, inspects the bytes it needs to inspect, and converts the fields byte by byte.

Comment: I insist. Here is the place I can convert sooner in the architecture, and unfortunately I can´t change the architecture. I have a `reportData` buffer of bytes and I need to map it to a managed structure to source other C# applications... A managed data buffer to a managed structure.... David - no serialization involved. It´s a byte protocol on the other side... embedded software built on C++... And I don´t want to build several deserializers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the new information from the comments, as I understand it:

- The byte array arrives over the network.
- The byte array is generated by some embedded C++ code (in other words, not using the .Net class that your code uses).
- The byte array can be converted to several possible classes, of which `ReportDataStruct` is just one possibility.

Your choices are to write some methods to convert byte arrays into .Net objects, or have something in the .Net framework do that conversion for you. **There is no way to take a byte array's memory and directly use it as a managed reference type.**

Given those two choices, I would choose to do the conversion myself, because it's much easier to verify that it's correct. To get the .Net framework to do the conversion, you're going to have to spend time with the attributes in the [InteropServices namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to make the Marshal class use the same memory representation as the embedded C++ code does. If the representation is slightly off, it would be easy for subtle bugs to creep in, which is less likely with an explicit Deserialize method.